# Rust Generics - Wrapping a Generic Container with T = f32 and f64

Tags: generics, rust

In Rust, the types `f32` and `f64` do not implement ordering.

If I have a generic container, for the sake of example let's consider a `BTreeSet<T>`, I may want to wrap that in some other type so that I can interact with its API in terms of `f32` and `f64`.

Since those types do not support ordering, this isn't going to work directly.

However, [there exists a crate](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/) which can wrap a float type to implement ordering.

I can certainly use `BTreeSet<T>` with `T = OrderedFloat`. However I want the API to present itself in terms of `T = f32, f64`.

I don't know how to do this.

One method would be to implement a marker trait for `f32` and `f64` and constrain `T` to be marker trait.

A sketch... Really pseudocode, probably lots of mistakes in the syntax here...

```
trait FloatLike {}

impl FloatLike for f32 {}

impl FloatLike for f64 {}

struct BTreeSetFloat<T: FloatLike> {

    btreeset: BTreeSet<OrderedFloat<T>>
}

impl<T> BTreeSetFloat {

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> Option<T> {
        let value = OrderedFloat::new(value);
        self.insert(value)
    }
    // ... etc for other functions
}
```

My question: Is this the correct method to constrain generics? Or is there a better way than having to add a somewhat arbitrary marker trait which serves no purpose other than to apply a constraint to `T`?

---

If the URL breaks: Search "Rust Ordered Float": `ordered-float = "3.9.0"`

---

After asking this question I discovered that `ordered_float` contains a trait `Float` which appears to be exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Define "correct". It works, and it's fine.

Comment: The types in `ordered-float` are also constrained to the trait [`Float`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html) found in `num-traits`, so you can use it as well.

Comment: @E_net4 just found that  - seems to be exactly the required thing